# Formatting MySQL datetime in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to format my DATETIME to spanish so it doesnt show like '2015-11-14 13:22:33'.

Actually I'm calling my datetime on a squery like this

```
$not_Fecha = $rows_result ['nw_Fecha'];
```

And formatting here (dias = days, meses = months):

```
    <?php  $not_Fecha = new DateTime($result->my_datetime);

$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
$meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

echo $result = $dias[date('w')]." ".date('d')." de ".$meses[date('n')-1]. " del ".date('Y'). " a las ".date('g:i A') ;

?>
```

But it shows the today's date, not the one stored in my database. What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use your date from the database. You only use `date()` which uses today (unless you give it a Unix timestamp of a different date). Replace your calls to date to use the `DateTime` object which represents  that actual date you want to work with.

```
<?php  
$not_Fecha = new DateTime($result->my_datetime);

$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
$meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

echo $result = $dias[$not_Fecha->format('w')]." ".$not_Fecha->format('d')." de ".$meses[$not_Fecha->format('n')-1]. " del ".$not_Fecha->format('Y'). " a las ".$not_Fecha->format('g:i A') ;
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/468988)

Comment: Thanks John, but I made the changes you suggested and it keeps showing today's date

Comment: What is the value of `$result->my_datetime`?

Comment: Maybe that's the error, it doesn't show any value, how could I make this code detect my $not_fecha? @john

Comment: Your error is then related to getting the data out of your database. You need to troubleshoot that and then this code will work.

Comment: With the squery I have, I use <?php echo $not_Fecha; ?> to call the datetime and it shows '2015-11-14 13:22:33', so getting the data isn't a problem

Comment: Then the first line of code you provided is also wrong. Try usimg `$not_Fecha = new DateTime($not_Fecha);).

Comment: Solved with that! Thank you so much John.